# Find min/max x,y in each vector<vector<Point>>

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I found contours in the image and I store their coordinates in vector < vector < Point >> like below:  [vector of vector(Point)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3UtQ.png)

I want to find xmax,xmin,ymax and ymin in each vector. 
[Min/Max coordinates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZkk8.png)
I have to write it down somewhere, so I could use these values in further part of my script.

```
vector<vector<Point> > contours1; 
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy1; 
findContours(testowy, contours1, hierarchy1, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

int xmax = 0;
int xymax = 0;
int ymax = 0;
int yxmax = 0;


for( int i = 0; i < contours1.size(); i++ ){
        for(int j=0; j < contours1[i].size();j++){

            if(contours1[i][j].x > xmax){
            xmax = contours1[i][j].x;
            xymax = contours1[i][j].y;   

            }                 

            if(contours1[i][j].y > ymax){
            ymax = contours1[i][j].y;
            yxmax = contours1[i][j].x;

            }  
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately my code can only find the biggest coordinate of all vectors.

Comment: take a look at [this](http://answers.opencv.org/question/64433) (the proposed solution maybe buggy on Rectangular shapes)

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that you basically want to find a single bounding box that fits all the contours?

Comment: @DanMašek No, I want to find contours and coordinates of their most advanced points.

Comment: @sturkmen Not exactly what I was looking for, but if turned out to be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: If you have a large number of elements, I would not recommend to use a vector of vector: there is a non-negligible overhead associated with vector, it is in general not recommented to nest STL classes. You may use Compressed Row Storage instead (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix). If the number of point is small (less than 1000) then you can ignore my remark.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct myclass {
    bool operator() (cv::Point pt1, cv::Point pt2) { return (pt1.y < pt2.y); }
} myobject;
sort(pnt.begin(), pnt.end(), myobject);
```

**use this simple code and replace pnt to your vector name and you can find max/min value in vector vecotr[0] have mix value and vector[last] have max value**